# Xcode Highlight area or button

Tags: ios7, xcode5

I have 20 storyboards, about 15 buttons added dragging and segue names in each VC. The correct button changes to the next View Controller, I want a HINT button to highlight the correct button to be pressed in the active view controller. It is a sequence of view controllers, each view controller has the correct and unique button to advance to the next view controller. Need Help. Cheers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to show tooltip on button using [CMTopView](https://github.com/chrismiles/CMPopTipView).

Comment: Hi Parcs, CMTopView highlight the button pressed or hovered, what I am looking forward is to click a HINT button and the correct (next) button in that VC is highlighted or blinks. :)

Comment: @Manolo: You can have the small 'i' (info) button over your button to show the tooltip, in this way you can show the information and the action you want to perform with the button click as well. I have implemented in this way.

Comment: I have in this way but I don't really like the way the message comes, I was looking to have pressed button and highlight the area to be touched next instead of writing where to press.

Comment: @Manolo : Ok, then you can add the borders and shadows to the next area where you want to direct the user.

Comment: I Park, what I do in the "i" info is to show a picture in another VC, is there a way to show a border without a new class or new VC??? this should be nice :)